# ReportViewer error when dynamically setting rdlc file on Azure Cloud Services

Tags: asp.net, azure, reportviewer

OK, this should be pretty easy but, I cannot figure out whats going on.
I have an ASP.NET web application that runs in an Azure Cloud Services and in one of the aspx pages there is a ReportViewer. At this page´s codebehind I dynamically add ReportViewer´s design .rdlc file with the line:

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("reports/myReportFile.rdlc");
```

When I run the report on localhost, everything works fine, but when I publish to Azure Cloud Services I get the following error:

> Could not find a part of the path
>   'F:\sitesroot\0\reports\myReportFile.rdlc'. Exception Details:
>   System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path 'F:\sitesroot\0\reports\myReportFile.rdlc'.

That should be obvious, right? The file path is invalid or the .rdlc file is not there.
I tried changing the .rdlc file properties on Visual Studio, setting "Copy to Output Directory" = "Copy always", and again I got exactly the same error.

Observations:
I´m publishing using Azure Tools/Package (.cscfg + .cspkg)  and uploading them through Azure Management Portal.

Any ideas on what I should do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple hours researching I found a solution here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f1eb4502-0549-4130-a0d9-9f9abf66c6ab/how-to-run-reportviewer-in-azure-?forum=windowsazuredevelopment

> For rdlc file, by default, the "Build Action" is "Embedded Resource"
>   causing that the file will be embedded in the DLL. Setting "Copy to
>   Output Directory" to "Copy always" causes the Report1.rdlc file will
>   be copied to the bin folder. After knowing this, there are two options
>   to resolve the issue:
>
> 1. Set the "Build Action" as "Content" then use "Report1.rdlc" in LocalReport.ReportPath Property.
> 2. Set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always" or "Copy if newer" then use "bin\Report1.rdlc" in in LocalReport.ReportPath Property.
>
> Wenchao Zeng

Suggestion #1 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

rdlc not found in report viewer in windows form application
Set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always" or "Copy if newer" then use "bin\Report1.rdlc" in in LocalReport.ReportPath Property